# Windows Forms Adding Text without Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I am using `Visual Studio 2019` in order to create a `Windows Form Application`. I need some titles in my application, which means these strings will not be modified by the user.

For now, I created textboxes for these titles and made these textboxes "read-only". However, this does not satisfy my aesthetical expectations.

Therefore, I wonder if there is a way to add a string without adding a textbox, to the form. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not try [Label Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/label-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using a [Label control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/label-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) rather than a TextBox.

The only time I would use a TextBox as a label is if I want the user to be able to copy the info, and I make it borderless, readonly and have the same colour as the background of the form. It's not superb UX though as there isn't anything that screams "you can highlight and copy this text" other than an I beam cursor, which is pretty much "mystery meat navigation" - better off putting a copy button next to it if you expect the user to copy info often

Comment: From CharithJ's answer: Double clicking on the label copies the text to clipboard. This is the default winforms Label functionality. You can add a toolTip control to improve the usability if you like.

Comment: Which probably goes further to compound the UX point; I've used windows systems for more than 20 years and never before knew "double click a WinForms label to copy its text" - nothing about a label affords a "you can double click this", and I typically avoid tooltips these days as they don't work out well for touch interfaces (plus, I probably wouldn't put a "double click to copy" in a tooltip). If you take a look at the file properties dialog you'll note that everything a user might reasonably want to copy is a textbox styled like a label so it shows the I beam cursor when hovered..

Comment: ..which is, again, not a great affordance for touch. Also worth noting that none of the labels in that dialog can be double clicked, so it kinda arrives at a "double click a label to copy it" is a bit of an an inconsistent curio and probably not something I'd utilize these days, personally (but thanks for the nugget of info! :D )

Comment: Hehe, full ack. I was surprised, too and thought I may as well share it..

Answer (score 4):

**Why not use Label for your titles?**

---

Since label, by default, cannot be modified by the user, thats what you want. Textbox is used for the user input, not for the titles.

Answer (score 0):

Use Label control that is the right control to use for your requirement